# How can I display first value of drop down box from one table and other values of same drop down from another table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> I have display the data from database into textbox and drop down box
>   from users table. I have one display button,when I click on display
>   button then the list of employees appear into textbox perfectly,but it
>   is not working perfectly into drop down box.I am fetching values of
>   dropdown from another table also,but I want to display the respective
>   value of employee department into the drop down box first.

```
<td><select name="Department" value="<%=pList.get(4)%>" style="width:150px">
         <%
         Statement statement1 = con.createStatement() ;
         resultset1 =statement1.executeQuery("select Department from users") ;
   while(resultset1.next()){ %>
            <option><%= resultset1.getString(1)%></option>

        <% } %>
    </select></td>
```

> I am getting first value of data from drop down box,but I want to
>   display the data of employee's department as first value into drop
>   down box .I have display the data of employee from users table and
>   department from department table into drop down box,but I want to
>   Display the data from users table as first value into dropdown box,and
>   then I can select another value and update the data.I am not getting
>   ,How can I implement these.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to display records in drop down as well as in text box.
So answer to your first question: You have missed out "option" tag in your code

> Try out below code :

```
<td><select name="Department1" value="<%=pList.get(4)%>" style="width:150px">
 <%
 Statement statement1 = con.createStatement() ;
 resultset1 =statement1.executeQuery("select Department from users") ;
 while(resultset1.next()){ %> 
<option>
      <%= resultset1.getString(1)%>
</option>

<% } %>
```

Answer to your second question : You want to display User's Data  first and then Employee's Data :

i would suggest take Users records in the list and then in same list add the employees records.

try to avoid JAVA code in JSP.

Not a good practice of writing JAVA code in JSP.

Comment: Sorry,There was copy paste mistake in my code.Option tag is already present,But I want to display department of employee 1 in the drop down from users table as first value .

Comment: Can you add an sample data of what exactly and how you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td><select name="Department"  style="width:150px" >
                    <OPTION value="<%=pList.get(4)%>"><%=pList.get(4)%></OPTION>
                    <%
                    Statement statement1 = con.createStatement() ;
                    resultset1 =statement1.executeQuery("select distinct Department from department") ;
   while(resultset1.next()){ %>
            <option ><%= resultset1.getString(1)%></option>

        <% } %></select></td>
```